# Existence of eigenvalue for real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n×n$ real symmetric matrix and let $S = \{x ∈ R^n: ||x|| = 1\}$ be the unit sphere
of $R^n$. Let $x ∈ S$ be such that $\langle Ax, x \rangle = sup_S\langle Ay, y \rangle$.
(By compactness, such an $x$ exists.)

(a) Prove that if $\langle x, y\rangle = 0$ then $\langle Ax, y\rangle = 0$. Hint: Expand
$\langle A(x + εy), x + εy\rangle$.

I am not sure where the $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$ condition is used, expanding the expression provided doesn't seem to provide anything useful.

Comment: I think if you show your work of expanding the expression, and using that $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, it will be easier to give you a hint at the next step. (it involves the definition of $x$)

Comment: When I expand the expression, $\langle x,y \rangle$ is not in the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint:
$$\langle A(x + \epsilon y), x + \epsilon y\rangle
= \langle Ax, x\rangle + 2 \epsilon \langle Ax, y \rangle + \epsilon^2 \langle A y, y \rangle$$

Using the condition $\langle x, y \rangle$:
$$\langle x + \epsilon y, x + \epsilon y \rangle = 1 + \epsilon^2 \|y\|^2$$

With $z_\epsilon := \frac{x + \epsilon y}{\|x + \epsilon y\|}$, combining the above two equations yields
\begin{align}
0 \ge \langle Az_\epsilon, z_\epsilon\rangle - \langle Ax, x\rangle
&= \frac{\langle Ax, x\rangle + 2 \epsilon \langle Ax, y \rangle + \epsilon^2 \langle A y, y \rangle}{1 + \epsilon^2 \|y\|^2}
- \langle Ax, x\rangle
\\
&
= \frac{- \epsilon^2 \|y\|^2\langle Ax, x\rangle + 2 \epsilon \langle Ax, y \rangle + \epsilon^2 \langle A y, y \rangle}{1 + \epsilon^2 \|y\|^2}.
\end{align}

In particular, the numerator should be nonpositive for any $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. However, if $\langle Ax, y \rangle \ne 0$, you can find an $\epsilon$ to make the numerator positive, leading to a contradiction.

When $\langle Ax, y \rangle = 0$, the numerator is $\epsilon^2 \|y\|^2 (\langle A(y/\|y\|), y/\|y\|\rangle - \langle Ax, x\rangle) \le 0$.)